# composer require appointer/swaggervel --dev problem with laravel v7.0

Tags: laravel

When i run the command `composer require appointer/swaggervel --dev` to added this package to my project i have this error

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for appointer/swaggervel ^2.5 -> satisfiable by appointer/swaggervel[v2.5].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.8.1
```

I did not understand what this error is and how I can correct it.

thank you in advance for answering my question.

Note : this is my composer.json file :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^7.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "7.0.x-dev",
    "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "7.0.x-dev",
    "infyomlabs/swagger-generator": "dev-master",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.2",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.4",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.11",
    "zircote/swagger-php": "2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error can be resolved unsing this [laravel package](https://packagist.org/packages/dagbouj-hatem/swaggervel)

```
composer require dagbouj-hatem/swaggervel --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the package you are trying to install doesn't support your current version of Laravel (7.8.1)

You can see below the code of the package [composer.json](https://github.com/appointer/swaggervel/blob/v2.5/composer.json):

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "illuminate/support": "^5.0|^6.0",
        "swagger-api/swagger-ui": "^3.1",
        "zircote/swagger-php": "^2.0"
    },
```

Comment: you could do a request to the author of the package to update the dependencies to support laravel 7.8.1 or you can fork their repository and update yourself the requirements & publish you newly forked package

Comment: Another solution is to use Laravel 6 for your project